# xpath accessing information in nodes

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

i need to scrap information form a website contain the property details.

```
<div class="inner">
<div class="col">
  <h2><a href="house-in-digana-for-sale-kandy-32">House in Digana </a></h2>
  <div class="meta">
      <div class="date"></div>
      <span class="category">Houses</span>,
    <span class="location">Kandy</span>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="attr polar">
    <span class="data">Rs. 3,600,000</span>
  </div>
```

what is the xpath notation for "Kandy" and "Rs. 3,600,000" ?

Answer (score 3):

It is not wise to address text nodes directly using `text()` because of nuances in an XML document.

Rather, addressing an element node directly returns the concatenation of all descendant text nodes as the element value, which is what people usually want (and think they are getting when they address text nodes).

The canonical example I use in the classroom is this example of OCR'ed content as XML:

```
<cost>39<!--that 9 may be an 8-->.22</cost>
```

The value of the element using the XPath address `cost` is "39.22", but in XSLT 1.0 the value of the XPath address `cost/text()` is "39" which is not complete.  In XSLT 2.0 (which is how the question is tagged), you get two text nodes "39" and ".22", which if you concatenate them it looks correct.  But, if you pass them to a function requiring a singleton argument, you will get a run-time error.  When you address an element, the text returned is concatenated into a single string, which is suitable for a singleton argument.

I tell students that in all of my professional work there are only very (very!) few times that I ever have to use `text()` in my stylesheets.

So `//span[@class='location' or @class='data']` would find the two fields if those were the only such elements in the entire document.  You may need to use ".//span" from a location inside of the document tree.

Comment: Your exploitation is right and a good one(!), but could be easily misunderstood. The important point in "_but in XSLT 1.0 the value of the XPath address cost/text() is "39"_" is the **value of**. The XPATH result of `cost/text()` even in xpaht-1.0 is a list of all direct child text nodes. Where `xsl:value-of` will return  only the first one, but `copy-of will` return all.

Comment: Thank you, hr_117, yes.  I was assuming the original poster was using <xsl:value-of> as most do.  But my caveat for XSLT 2.0 would certainly apply:  if the XPath address is used as the first argument to a function like `contains()`, there would be run-time error because the first argument is not a singleton.  My point I tell students is "if you think you need to use `text()`, then think again, because you probably don't"

Comment: Thinking more about this, in XSLT 1, `contains(cost,'2')` returns true, `contains(cost/text(),'2')` returns false, and in XSLT 2, `contains(cost/text(),'2')` returns a run-time error and the transformation abends.