# How to ignore the content of a <span> within a <h3> element using XPATH?

Tags: html, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have the following markup:

```
<h3 class="foo">I WANT THIS <span class="bar">I DON'T WANT THIS</span></h3>
```

Is there any way to get ignore the content of the `<span>` with XPATH? So far all efforts have been fruitless. Seems easy, but I can't for the life of me figure this out...

Just to be crystal clear - the result should be:

```
I WANT THIS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In his case `text()` should help.
Try `//h3/text()` (at least for xapth-1.0 I'm not sure if this will work with 2.0).

Comment: `//h3/text()` does the same in XPath 2.0 as in XPath 1.0, namely select the direct text child nodes of the `h3` elements. As the sample `h3` has a single text child node with contents `I WANT THIS` that is selected.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Thanks, I only was not 100% sure because of discussion at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17244844/2115381

Comment: Problems can arise but as far as we have seen the input sample they should not. Depending on the exact needs of the poster it might help to use `//h3/text()[1]` to for instance select only `foo` in `<h3>foo<span>bar</span>whatever</h3>`. But it could as well be that `foowhatever` is needed, then with XPath 2.0 doing `string-join(//h3/text(), '')` would do, so the path remains as posted. I agree with Ken that often selecting the element is cleaner as selecting text child nodes but with mixed content as in this question accessing text child nodes is necessary.